# Which ThemeData property changes component background color?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, mobile

I'm starting to work with ThemeData, but I have some problems.

In my code, I have a CircleAvatar and several Containers that should be colored. To make it work in light and dark theme, I use a themeData.

I can change the text, the background color etc, but for the CircleAvatar and the Container I can't find, do you know what I should put?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> If a [backgroundColor] is not specified, the theme's
> [ThemeData.primaryColorLight] is used with dark foreground colors, and
> [ThemeData.primaryColorDark] with light foreground colors.

as mention in flutter doc. you can do this:

```
Theme(
   data: ThemeData(
       primaryColorDark: Colors.red,
   ),
   child: CircleAvatar(
       radius: 30,
   ),
 ),
```

but in container you can set default value in theme data, because generally container has no color.